# How to Filter Search Results by Post Type on Frontend?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, frontend, custom-post-type

**Update:** I might have explained the question a little better, so I re-wrote it here 
[How can I Split Search Results into Post Types Tabs on Frontend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448872/how-can-i-split-search-results-into-post-types-tabs-on-frontend)

I have a Wordpress Site and I have 4 x Post Types. WHen I do a Search all 4 Post Types are displayed in the results.

What I would like is for the user to be able to filter these results by Post Type.

For example, lets say I have 4 x Post Types

Could I have above the results a set of radio buttons to help filter

- All Results (by default)
- Filter by Post Type 1
- Filter by Post Type 2
- Filter by Post Type 3
- Filter by Post Type 4

That way the user could easily find the exact content they are looking for instead of giving content from ALL POST TYPES all the time and that's it!

Note: I assume the best way are radio buttons but I guess the field could be a drop down too.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177768/wordpress-custom-search-by-post-type

Comment: Hi thanks for the link, however I think that deals with how to filter the results when I search something. What I want to do is do a search and then have radio buttons that filter the results which the user can use. Not Click a radio button and then repeat a search. It is more a real time filter. Maybe pressing a filter does refresh a search, not sure. I guess these radion buttons could be tabs too!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter results on the fly, you'll want to look either into an AJAX solution (if you're dealing with potentially thousands of results) or using Javascript/jQuery to toggle the visibility of results based on their post-type. A simple solution would be something like this using jQuery.

In your search.php template:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input class="radioToggle" type="radio" name="post_type" value="type1" />Filter 1<br/>
    <input class="radioToggle" type="radio" name="post_type" value="type2" />Filter 2<br/>
    <input class="radioToggle" type="radio" name="post_type" value="type3" />Filter 3<br/>
</form>
<div class="result type1">
    result of type 1....
</div>
<div class="result type2">
    result of type 2....
</div>
<div class="result type2">
    result of type 2....
</div>
<div class="result type3">
    result of type 3....
</div>
<div class="result type3">
    result of type 3....
</div>
<div class="result type3">
    result of type 3....
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($))
    {
        $(".radioToggle").click(function()
        {
            $(".result."+$(this).attr("value")).css("display", "block");
            $(".result:not(."+$(this).attr("value")+")").css("display", "none");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is untested, and I would personally avoid doing this on the fly altogether. I'm of the personal belief that search results should be filtered beforehand using PHP, not afterwards using Javascript. But still, if this is necessary for your UI, then this should help get you started.

Remember that in order to utilize this method, jQuery will need to be installed or enqueued by your theme.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment. I think I rushed the above question when writing it, so I better explained what I am trying to do over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448872/how-can-i-split-search-results-into-post-types-tabs-on-frontend thanks