# How can I Split Search Results into Post Types Tabs on Frontend?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, custom-post-type

I have a Wordpress Installation. I have about 3 x custom post types on my site. When I do a search, all post type results get displayed on the front end on 1 page. Some post types are totally different from others content wise so the results look a bit funny.

Is there a way to split the results into tabs according to post type? I want to leave the results as default the way they are now (All Results) but then have tabs to the right filtering out the different results according to post type they belong to.

I created a jpeg here to help explain exactly what I am trying to do.

Thanks

http://f.cl.ly/items/110S2K1A0T3m290Y0C14/Filter_post_Types.jpg

[image]

**Update 1:**
Just wanted to add a bit more info on the code side

I was planning on using shortcodes as tabs

```
[tabs]
[tab]All Search Results[/tab]
[tab]Post Type 1 Results[/tab]
[tab]Post Type 1 Results[/tab]
[tab]Post Type 1 Results[/tab]
[tab]
```

or in PHP Template I can also do it by

```
<?php 

echo do_shortcode('[tabs style="boxed" id="searchTabs"]
   [tab title="Post Type 1"]Post Type 1 Results[/tab]
   [tab title="Post Type 2"]Post Type 2 Results[/tab]
   [tab title="Post Type 3"]Post Type 3 Results[/tab]
   [/tabs]');

?>
```

I am thinking there is something here that can help me, but not sure how to implement it http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

**Update 2:**
Other advice I have received on another forum is to try code like this, but I cannot seem to implement it correctly to my search template php which is here http://pastie.org/4248751

The code suggested was

```
<?php
$the_slug = 'my_slug';
$args=array(
  'name' => $the_slug,
  'post_type' => 'custom_post_Type_1',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => 1
);
$my_posts = get_posts($args);

$the_slug2 = 'my_slug2';
$args2=array(
  'name' => $the_slug2,
  'post_type' => 'custom_post_Type_2',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => 1
);
$my_posts2 = get_posts($args2);

echo do_shortcode('[tabs style="boxed" id="searchTabs"]

   [tab title="Post Type 1"]
        <?php //This code is for first post type
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>

            <li><a>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
   [/tab]

   [tab title="Post Type 2"]
       <?php //This code is for second post type
       foreach( $myposts2 as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>

            <li><a>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
   [/tab]

   [/tabs]');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry - understand now.

User different loops in each tab.

First tab:

```
<?php 
global $post; 
rewind_posts();
$query = new WP_Query(array(
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
));
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
?>

<!-- YOUR OUTPUT CODE HERE -->

<?php 
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Each other tab would have the same loop, but with an added parameter in the query

```
<?php 
global $post; 
rewind_posts();
$query = new WP_Query(array(
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'post_type' => 'post_type_name',
));
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
?>

<!-- YOUR OUTPUT CODE HERE -->

<?php 
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: thanks man, I tried looking into your code but can't figure out how to implement it into my search form php template :( Would you be able to guide me further knowing this is my search template http://pastie.org/4248751 ? thanks a lot!

Comment: I also updated my original post above with an edit and some more code to maybe help

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery to achieve this, not sure if everyone would agree, but I've tried it and it worked for me.

When Wordpress displays search results, each  has a classname reflecting the post type, for example

```
<article class="page type-page ....">blah blah blah</article>
```

For the (All results tab), you can use jQuery with something like:

```
$('.search-results .type-page').clone('.tab1');
```

Run the above function first so a copy of all the results is cloned into the first tab. As for the other tabs, you can begin to cut and paste the appropriate sections into them using:

```
$('.search-results .type-page').appendTo('.tab2');
```

Since you're using shortcode for tabs, make sure you inspect the generated tabs code and grab the correct classname for each tab to replace ('.tab1'), and/or ('.tab2') above. You can run the function on $document.ready and it should work. Let me know if I'm not too clear or just plain wrong..

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It is code for 2 post types in one tab, I have also two more tabs changing content on line 'post_type' => array ( 'post', 'aktualnosci')

```
      <?php
      $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        's' => $s,
        'post_type' => array ( 'post', 'aktualnosci')
      );
      query_posts($args);
      if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
              <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                  <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', array( 'class' => "img-responsive"));?>
                  <div class="caption">
                      <span class="ilabel">
                      <?php 
                      if ( get_post_type() == 'post' )  {
                        echo 'Oferta';
                      }
                      else {
                        echo 'Aktualności';
                      }
                      ; ?>
                      </span>
                      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                      <p>
                        <?php //first sentence excerpt only
                        $strings = preg_split('/(\.|!|\?)\s/', strip_tags($post->post_content), 2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
                        echo apply_filters('the_content', $strings[0] .  $strings[1]);?>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </a>
          </div>
      <?php
```